# Failing to install Sparkmagic using pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, unix, pyspark, pip

I am trying to install sparkmaic in jupyter notebook through pip but getting below error:

Command:

```
pip install sparkmagic
```

error:

```
Collecting gssapi>=1.6.0
  Using cached gssapi-1.8.1.tar.gz (94 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/e004255/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/e004255/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/e004255/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-guoi_e0p/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-guoi_e0p/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-guoi_e0p/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 109, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 22, in get_output
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'krb5-config --libs gssapi' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system is missing a tool named `krb5-config`. You might be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt install krb5-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @bernhard
but, I had to install dev tools too (ubuntu 20.04).

```
sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```